# Significance levels for multiple testing adjusted p-values

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni

May I ask what is the *conventional* significance levels for multiple testing adjusted p-values (no matter Bonferroni or Holm or Sidak)? For unadjusted p-values, many researchers use * 5%, ** 1% and *** 0.1%. Are those levels applied to the adjusted p-values? Is there any common agreement on this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conventional cut-offs for adjusted *p*-values are the same as for unadjusted *p*-values.  That is, if someone were inclined to use *alpha* = 0.05 as the threshold for "significance" on a single hypothesis test, they would be inclined to use *alpha* = 0.05 for a family of hypothesis tests with adjusted *p*-values.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I guessed.